# Authorizing OneDrive user in C# causes program to crash mysteriously

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am writing a console app with .Net Core version 3.1. The purpose is to allow a user to access Microsoft OneDrive accounts and fiddle with them as desired. Getting past the authorizing stage is proving difficult. Here is a code snippet demonstrating what I have going:

```
//using statements
namespace HelloOneDrive
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task handleThing = (new Thing()).Handle();
        }
    }

    public class Thing
    {
        public async Task Handle()
        {
            ClientCredentialProvider credentials;
            string tenantId = //value
            string clientId = //value
            string clientSecret = //value
            AuthenticationResult authResult;
            string[] scopes = { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
            GraphServiceClient client = null;

            try
            {
                credentials = new ClientCredentialProvider(ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                    .Create(clientId)
                    .WithTenantId(tenantId)
                    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                    .Build());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //[logic for handling an exception, that never gets thrown]
            }

            try
            {
                authResult = await credentials
                .ClientApplication
                .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                .ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //[logic for handling an exception, that never gets thrown]
                //The program fails silently and suddenly, rather than hit
                //this catch block.
                Console.WriteLine("hello");
            }

            if (authResult != null)
            {
                client = new GraphServiceClient(
                    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                        requestMessage =>
                        {
                            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }));
            }

            if (client != null)
            {
                ...
```

The debugger will get to the second `try-catch` block, try to define `authResult`, and then suddenly end. No exception is caught; the program just ends.

In case it is useful, the NuGet packages I am using are:

- Microsoft.Graph v3.21.0
- Microsoft.Graph.Auth v1.0.0-preview.6
- Microsoft.Graph.Core v1.23.0 (v2.0.0-preview.4)
- Microsoft.Identity.Client v4.24.0

Help?

Comment: How do you know an exception isn't thrown? Your code catches exceptions and then throws them away. You wouldn't see anything unless you do something within the catch blocks. Suppressing valid exceptions is an anti-pattern.

Comment: My actual code handles the exception; however, for the sake of brevity, I did not include the logic, just like I did not include my `using` statements, or the values of some of my variables. I know the code does not catch any exceptions, because I have run the debugger through it line by line several times, and witnessed the occurrence. ^_^

Comment: Could you edit the code sample to make it more clear what you're doing with the exceptions? Right now, your comments look like you're reminding yourself to implement the exception handling.

Comment: Ok. It really wasn't clear at all from your sample. You'd be surprised how many people use an empty catch just to dodge an exception, and then it comes back to bite them when they can't diagnose errors. Anyway, so there's nothing in your exception log when the code mysteriously ends? And it never gets to the `if (authResult != null)` line at all? .NET programs don't just randomly stop normally. Is there anything in the main windows event log, perhaps?

Comment: There is nothing in my exception log, and it never gets to the `if` block. `The program '[30860] HelloOneDrive.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).` is the only thing of value output by the debugger, which only confirms that the program is simply ending for some reason.

Comment: It doesn't matter what happens with the exceptions, as no exception is ever thrown ^_^

Comment: Is there anything in the windows event log (rather than your exception log) about it? This is extremely unusual behaviour. I assume you're running it from visual studio and rather than standalone? Is there any difference in behaviour if you build it and run it from the command line directly? (Obviously you might want to add some extra logging as you don't have the debugger).

Comment: Executing from the command line appears to do nothing useful, which is what I would expect. There is nothing related to my program mentioned in any Windows Event log after I run it.  The program simply tries to execute the line `authResult = ...` and exits, rather than continuing on to the `if` block.

Comment: If it doesn't make it to the next line, the only logical explanation is that it enters the catch block instead (and then doesn't come out for some reason). There is no other explanation, in any kind of regular usage. Are you 100% certain this doesn't happen? Have you set a breakpoint on the first line of the catch block? Maybe we could see the code for that catch block?

Comment: I am 100% certain that the code never enters the `catch` section of the `try-catch` block. Yes, I have made proper use of break points. The code inside the catch block is irrelevant, as it never reaches that point ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling an `async` method from a non-async `Main` and not waiting for the result. Thus, your `Handle()` method is executed synchronously until it reaches the first async call. (`authResult = await credentials...`) Then the synchronous execution flow is handed back to the `Main` method, which has nothing else to do, so it exits. And if the `Main` method comes to an end, of course the whole process ends because the runtime does not wait for running Tasks to complete unless you explicitely tell it to do so.

You could for instance `Wait()` for the task in the `Main` method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Task handleThing = (new Thing()).Handle();
  handleThing.Wait();
}
```

or you could make your `Main` async as well, and then `await` your `Handle()` Task

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
  await (new Thing()).Handle();
}
```

Comment: `handleThing.Wait()` did the trick; thank you so much! ^_^